# Check the size of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to find out if the size of this array is `6` or more. I am counting the second level (where is says `size=10`). What's the simplest method?

Here it is dumped:

```
ARRAY (SIZE=1)
  0 => 
    ARRAY (SIZE=10)
      'ID' => INT 35
      'ALT' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'TITLE' => STRING 'FD-7' (LENGTH=4)
      'CAPTION' => STRING 'THIS IS THE FIFTH CAPTION FOR THE PHOTOGRAPH.' (LENGTH=45)
      'DESCRIPTION' => STRING '' (LENGTH=0)
      'MIME_TYPE' => STRING 'IMAGE/JPEG' (LENGTH=10)
      'URL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/02/FD-7.JPG' (LENGTH=61)
      'WIDTH' => INT 432
      'HEIGHT' => INT 650
      'SIZES' => 
        ARRAY (SIZE=9)
          'THUMBNAIL' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/02/FD-7.JPG' (LENGTH=61)
          'THUMBNAIL-WIDTH' => INT 63
          'THUMBNAIL-HEIGHT' => INT 96
          'MEDIUM' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/02/FD-7.JPG' (LENGTH=61)
          'MEDIUM-WIDTH' => INT 432
          'MEDIUM-HEIGHT' => INT 650
          'LARGE' => STRING 'HTTP://FASHION-DETAIL.DEV/WP-CONTENT/UPLOADS/2014/02/FD-7.JPG' (LENGTH=61)
          'LARGE-WIDTH' => INT 432
          'LARGE-HEIGHT' => INT 650
```

Comment: Do you mean `count($array[0])`?

Answer (score 1):

Apply `COUNT_RESURSIVE` flag for [`count()`](http://php.net/count):

```
$result = count($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
```

-for entire array. If you want to count only certain element, pass it like:

```
//$key is your element's index
$result = count($array[$key]);
```

Finally, to get only counts from second level, you can apply:

```
$array = [
   ['foo', 'bar'],
   ['baz'],
   [],
   ['bee', 'feo']
];

$result = array_sum(array_map('count', $array));//5
```

Comment: As described in example #2 on http://br2.php.net/count this will return the overall count, which does not help the questioner

Comment: It will, yes. And I've mentioned that.

Comment: So what? Feel free to dv then. That's how SO works. And if edit was made to improve answer - then it's my right to do that. Please, be more tolerant (and there were 3 edits, including last).

Comment: That's not the point. In your previous comment you claim that you mentioned what I corrected in my first comment. And when I wrote my first comment you did not mention it. Anyway your answer is correct "now"